# On a system on which the PIC does not support masking, how does software disablement of hard interrupts work?

Tags: operating-system, interrupt, pic

In particular, how is a hard interrupt deferred? In the same system, when is an interrupt deferred by software eventually executed?

------not a homework question, studying for an exam

Answer (score 0):

Is this specifically for PIC?

On a PIC processor, you could clear the individual interrupt's enable flag. For example, Timer 2 has a `TMR2IE` bit that could be cleared. At that point, the interrupt won't be serviced until `TMR2IE` is set... If you want the ISR to make that determination, you can clear the enable and not the flag from within the ISR and then once you exit, it will still be waiting.

Not sure if this help.

Comment: The individual interrupt enable flags comprise the mask, and the question stipulates that the PIC in question does not support masking.

Answer (score 0):

If your system is x86 based, then you would issue a CLI (Clear Interrupt FLag) command. While this flag is cleared, the processor will not respond to external interrupts signaled on the INTR pin.

When you want to re-enable interrupt handling, issue an STI (Set Interrupt Flag) command. The processor will then respond to signals on the INTR pin, as usual.

In the original IBM PC, you could also mask NMI by writing 0x00 to port 0xA0, and re-enable it by writing 0x80 to the same port. This was not a processor feature, but an external software-controllable switch on the mainboard. I'm not sure if you can still do that in modern processors.